# Where do I find information about Blog APIs and how to use them?

Tags: api, blogs

I'm thinking of creating a small offline blog editor for personal use and I don't know how do the APIs work. Where can I find this information?

I'm particularly looking for the most common providers: Blogger, Wordpress, MovableType, Live Spaces (not sure if this has an API) etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following links:

[Blogger](http://www.blogger.com/developers/api/1_docs/)

[Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)

[Live Spaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447732.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The Blogger API link you provided says:

> This documentation is provided for
>   historical interest only. The Blogger
>   1.0 API is no longer supported and must not be used for new client
>   development. Please use our GData API 
>   instead.

So the correct one probably is: http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/

Also, if more APIs are answered in this question, would you be kind enough to edit your answer to include them. Since I'm gonna vote it as the correct one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

MovableType API : http://www.sixapart.com/developers/xmlrpc/movable_type_api/

MetaWeblog API : http://www.xmlrpc.com/metaWeblogApi